# Snowflake how to return query string from execute method

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a Snowflake procedure, for brevity, lets just say it just runs a query using `snowflake.execute`

```
var rs = snowflake.execute( { sqlText:
`
  CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW DATABASE.SCHEMA.VIEW_NAME_HERE AS
  SELECT
    column1
    ,${stuff}     as column2
    ,${morestuff} as column3

  FROM DATABASE.SCHEMA.TABLE_SOURCE_HERE
`

                            } );
  return rs
```

How do i return `rs` so that it shows the query that it's running? I'm just getting an `[object object]` result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Statement object has a method called getSqlText():

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-api.html#getSqlText

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_proc() 
RETURNS STRING 
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT 
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS 
$$ 
    snowflake.execute( {sqlText: "create or replace table test (col string)"} ); 
    var column = 'col';
    var stmt = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: `SELECT MAX(${column}) FROM test`} ); 
    var ret = stmt.execute();
    
    return stmt.getSqlText();
$$ ; 

call my_proc();
```

It returns:

```
SELECT MAX(col) FROM test
```

Comment: Got it, so I must use ```createStatement``` in order to achieve what I'm trying to do? I can't call getSqlTest or something equivalent from the ```execute``` method?

Comment: That's right. snowflake.execute() returns ResultSet object, not Statement object:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-api.html#execute

And getSqlText() is a method from Statement Object.